# Syntax highlighting for Fastlane configuration files in Intellij CE

Tags: intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting, fastlane

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.2 (Community Edition), currently for Flutter development. When I open a `Podfile`, that is like a build script for an iOS app, and which seems to be a valid Ruby file in the inside, then the editor applies proper syntax highlighting. That is great.

Now, I also need to work with the configuration files of Fastlane, which are called `Fastfile` and `Appfile`. These also seem to be Ruby files. However, the editor treats them as plain text, and does not apply proper syntax highlighting.

My question is, is there any way to get IntelliJ to apply the same syntax highlighting rules that are applied to `Podfile`s to the Fastlane files as well?

In fact I could not even figure out which plugin provides the syntax highlighting for `Podfile` files. Is there a way to find that out?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Settings/Preferences | Editor | File Types
2. Add your file type (Fastlane)
3. specify syntax rules (braces, brackets, comments, etc)
4. specify keywords to highlight (desc do end lane platform)
5. Add file patterns matching these rules - Fastfile, Matchfile, Gymfile...

See also official documentation - [File type associations](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-registering-file-types.html)

Comment: Thank you @Sneg. I am hoping to find a solution where I do not have to redefine the syntax rules from scratch. Instead I would try to use the same rules that are applied for Podfiles. Which must already exist somewhere. I wonder how to find them.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this for the Podfile in an iOS / Flutter app.

The best I could get was

1. Install the Ruby plugin for Intellij
2. Right click on the file
3. Select "Edit type association"
4. Pick "Ruby"

That will at least give you syntax highlighting.